# Recommended workflow for long-running create process

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing a RESTful API that involves clients submitting requests to create a resource, let's say a report. For valid reasons not worth getting into, this process can take a minimum of 30 seconds and a maximum of several minutes to complete successfully. I'm trying to ensure this API is easy and intuitive to work with so I just want to get some feedback on what I was thinking of doing.

1. Client `POST`s request body to `/reports`
2. Server responds with `202 Accepted` and `Location: /jobs/{jobId}` header
3. Client `GET`s `/jobs/{jobId}` and receives `200 OK` and response body like `{"status": "pending"}` (abbreviated)
4. Client retries until they get `200 OK` (unchanged) and a body like
   `{
   "status": "complete",
   "location": "/reports/{reportId}",
   details": { ... }}
   }`
5. Client `GET`s `/reports/{reportId}` to retrieve their report

Some things I've though of doing differently from the above:

1. Having the `/jobs/{jobId}` resource return `303 See Other` with a `Location: /reports/{reportId}` header when ready. A number of blog posts & SO answers I saw took that approach. I decided against it because we want to retain these jobs as first-class resources, e.g. we want to be able to view all jobs submitted in the past 24 hours, all failed jobs in the past 15 minutes, etc. Also it seems `303 See Other` really should not return a body as clients should be expected to redirect to the `Location` url so they wouldn't see it anyway.
2. Having client `POST` to `/jobs` instead of `/reports`. I feel like either choice is defensible but it seems less surprising to clients that if they want to create a `report` they should `POST` to `/reports`. That being said, it may be surprising to get a response pointing them to a `job` instead of a `report`.
3. Whether clients `POST` to `/reports` or `/jobs`, since I am immediately creating a `job`, maybe I should return `201 Created` instead of `202 Accepted`.

Anyway, that's where my thinking currently is on this. Any confirmation, suggestions, respectfully explained disagreements, etc. are all greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: My first thought was to leverage WebHooks or allow clients to pass along a callback url. Besides that have you considered allowing clients to poll reports/{reportid}/jobstatus ? Seems a more logical fit to me.

Comment: @RobbertDraaisma `/reports/{reportId}/jobstatus` is an interesting idea but it seems wrong to do that if `/reports/{reportId}` has not been created yet. I considered synchronously creating a skeleton `report` object immediately that gets filled in when the report is ready but I don't want clients to have to process two different kinds of `report` objects in the collection. Re: Webhooks/callback URLs, we still need something like the `/jobs` collection for monitoring & batch clients who can't use push methods like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we want to retain these jobs as first-class resources, e.g. we want to be able to view all jobs submitted in the past 24 hours, all failed jobs in the past 15 minutes, etc.

If both jobs and reports are first-class, then I suggest giving each the usual obvious, boring semantics:

- `POST /jobs` returns `201 Created` and a `Location: /jobs/{id}` header. After all, the *job* was immediately created (the report is N/A).

  - Optionally you could have this return an `ETag` header (see next).
- `GET /jobs/{id}` returns `200 OK`; the response body indicates the readiness of the report and (if ready) the URI to `/reports/{id}`.

  - Optionally you could have this handle `If-None-Match` by returning `304 Not Modified` until the readiness changes. And of course return an `ETag` header.
- Of course `GET /reports/{id}` works.

---

p.s. If I'm not mistaken, `Location` headers ought to be full URIs e.g. `https://example.com/path/to/thing` not just relative paths `/path/to/thing`. If you do that, probably do likewise with any JSON response `location` values? That way, clients can just use the values as-is when making requests -- which is both more convenient for them, and better for you if they don't hardcode the protocol/host.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I think you’re right. The fact is that the request body is not a report representation to be persisted and added to the reports collection, it contains the data that the system needs to perform lots of calculations to produce the report, but the report looks nothing at all like the request. Therefore it does make more sense to think in terms of jobs, and the report is a side effect of this job being created. Much obliged!

Comment: And yes, I was being brief/sloppy above but will use absolute URIs for Location. 304/ETag makes sense but for simplicity and priority that may be something we add later. Thanks again!